# DD-WRT - No Internet on University's login-protected WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt

I'm trying to set up a DD-WRT router with OpenVPN so I don't have to bother with running the clients on all my devices (and, of course, because tinkering is fun!) However, I'm currently unable to access the internet via the router, even with a fresh firmware after a 30/30/30 reset.

I suspect this is because the router connects to my university's network which normally requires a username/password input on a website OR that the device in question be registered with the system via a MAC address. I already have the DD-WRT's MAC Address registered in the system but I still cannot get on the internet when running through the router, and I have no idea where to start debugging this.

My dorm has a university-run Aruba router physically installed in the room to which I have my DD-WRT router wired via the router's Internet jack. My desktop is also connected to the university's router via Ethernet, and has no problems. If I disconnect my desktop's ethernet and try to go solely over the DD-WRT router, I get no internet.

My ifconfig (with wlp32s0 being my DD-WRT router) is

```
enp30s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.137.108.60  netmask 255.255.192.0  broadcast 10.137.127.255
        inet6 fe80::4ecc:6aff:fefd:4462  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 4c:cc:6a:fd:44:62  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 182521  bytes 108612336 (103.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 38105  bytes 3970172 (3.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xfd500000-fd51ffff  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        ...

wlp32s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.124  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::cb99:9a97:fc89:2bb1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 18:d6:c7:e5:f3:d1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 17706  bytes 13350200 (12.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19210  bytes 1988154 (1.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Am I out of luck or is there some configuration wizardry that I can employ here?

Comment: Did you register the correct address (i.e. of the WAN interface)? Have you tried contacting the university's network admins? _They're_ the ones with access to firewall logs and everything useful.